# Spring Boot 2.3.4 + OpenJ9: Unhandled exception

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, adoptopenjdk, openj9

During last days we are suffering a lot of JVM crashes. We have been using OpenJ9 (8 & 11) without any problems, but some days ago we have started to have a lot of crashes. Two examples from today:

```
    Unhandled exception
    Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
    J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000018 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
    Handler1=00007FE3E0A0F0A0 Handler2=00007FE3E02FEA60 InaccessibleAddress=000055DAB1FD3000
    RDI=000055DAB1FB8E5B RSI=0000000000000200 RAX=000055DAB1FD3000 RBX=00007FE3BBE38640
    RCX=00007FE3DE7789E7 RDX=0000000000001402 R8=00007FE3E0AD42FF R9=0000000000000200
    R10=0000000000000003 R11=0000000000000001 R12=00007FE3E0AD4128 R13=00007FE3BBE38448
    R14=0000000000000001 R15=00007FE3BBE38640
    RIP=00007FE3E0A9A3E0 GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=00007FE3BBE38440
    EFlags=0000000000010206 CS=0033 RBP=0000000000000002 ERR=0000000000000006
    TRAPNO=000000000000000E OLDMASK=0000000000000000 CR2=000055DAB1FD3000
    xmm0 0114b4d70025b62a (f: 2471466.000000, d: 1.887162e-303)
    xmm1 b54c590116b75901 (f: 381114624.000000, d: -5.919270e-52)
    xmm2 590115d82a0010c7 (f: 704647360.000000, d: 5.514824e+120)
    xmm3 b900e70016b4d72c (f: 380950304.000000, d: -4.069092e-34)
    xmm4 0999011bb62b000a (f: 3056271360.000000, d: 1.985176e-262)
    xmm5 b40011b4d7570119 (f: 3612803328.000000, d: -3.199957e-58)
    xmm6 b4d72c0117b54d59 (f: 397757792.000000, d: -3.780091e-54)
    xmm7 0010c72c4d0117b4 (f: 1291917184.000000, d: 2.333271e-308)
    xmm8 2c03590019bd0500 (f: 431817984.000000, d: 1.132243e-96)
    xmm9 0000000041000000 (f: 1090519040.000000, d: 5.387880e-315)
    xmm10 000000003fa00000 (f: 1067450368.000000, d: 5.273906e-315)
    xmm11 40d70eab41ea1e65 (f: 1105862272.000000, d: 2.361068e+04)
    xmm12 000000003df950b9 (f: 1039749312.000000, d: 5.137044e-315)
    xmm13 00000000464fe674 (f: 1179641472.000000, d: 5.828203e-315)
    xmm14 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm15 40fc85cbcbe05a39 (f: 3420477952.000000, d: 1.168287e+05)
    Module=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so
    Module_base_address=00007FE3E097B000
    Target=2_90_20200715_697 (Linux 4.18.0-147.13.2.el8_1.x86_64)
    CPU=amd64 (4 logical CPUs) (0x7c2a8c000 RAM)
    ----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
    (0x00007FE3E0A9A3E0 [libj9vm29.so+0x11f3e0])
    (0x00007FE3E0A9BDB3 [libj9vm29.so+0x120db3])
    (0x00007FE3E0A9C9FB [libj9vm29.so+0x1219fb])
    (0x00007FE3E0A9CC97 [libj9vm29.so+0x121c97])
    (0x00007FE3E0A9CDBF [libj9vm29.so+0x121dbf])
    (0x00007FE3E0A78AD2 [libj9vm29.so+0xfdad2])
    (0x00007FE3E0A74330 [libj9vm29.so+0xf9330])
    (0x00007FE3D96A417D [libj9jvmti29.so+0x917d])
    (0x00007FE35ADC3C9B [libinstrument.so+0x4c9b])
    (0x00007FE3C16D7F68 [<unknown>+0x0])
    ---------------------------------------
```

or this longer one

```
    Unhandled exception
    Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
    J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000018 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000002
    Handler1=00007F70176C30A0 Handler2=00007F7016FB2A60 InaccessibleAddress=00007F6F80319000
    RDI=00007F6F801BC90B RSI=00007F6F80318FFE RAX=0000000000000F00 RBX=00007F6FF00DE640
    RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=00007F70121BFBFF R8=00007F70177882FF R9=0000000000000200
    R10=0000000000000003 R11=0000000000000001 R12=00007F7017788128 R13=00007F6FF00DE448
    R14=0000000000000001 R15=00007F6FF00DE640
    RIP=00007F701774E410 GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=00007F6FF00DE440
    EFlags=0000000000010206 CS=0033 RBP=0000000000000002 ERR=0000000000000006
    TRAPNO=000000000000000E OLDMASK=0000000000000000 CR2=00007F6F80319000
    malloc(): memory corruption
    Unhandled exception
    Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
    J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000018 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
    Handler1=00007F70176C30A0 Handler2=00007F7016FB2A60 InaccessibleAddress=0000000000000004
    RDI=0000000000000000 RSI=0000000000000000 RAX=0000000000000001 RBX=00007F70185FF531
    RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=0000000000000B00 R8=000000003A2DC13B R9=0000000000000004
    R10=00000000ED5C6C80 R11=00007F7018D71EA0 R12=00007F70185FF518 R13=0000000000000000
    R14=00007F701003E0A0 R15=00007F701003E0A0
    RIP=00007F7014BF960B GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=00007F70185FF460
    EFlags=0000000000010246 CS=0033 RBP=00007F70185FF508 ERR=0000000000000004
    TRAPNO=000000000000000E OLDMASK=0000000000000000 CR2=0000000000000004
    xmm0 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm1 69676e652f6c7173 (f: 795636096.000000, d: 5.604828e+199)
    xmm2 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm3 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm4 43e0000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 9.223372e+18)
    xmm5 000000003dd58307 (f: 1037402880.000000, d: 5.125451e-315)
    xmm6 000000004a09b01c (f: 1242148864.000000, d: 6.137031e-315)
    xmm7 0000000000000005 (f: 5.000000, d: 2.470328e-323)
    xmm8 010000000e000d00 (f: 234884352.000000, d: 7.291122e-304)
    xmm9 000000004901d000 (f: 1224855552.000000, d: 6.051590e-315)
    xmm10 000000003f800000 (f: 1065353216.000000, d: 5.263544e-315)
    xmm11 415a267974e94acc (f: 1961446144.000000, d: 6.855142e+06)
    xmm12 0000000040c481b4 (f: 1086620032.000000, d: 5.368617e-315)
    xmm13 000000004937cbec (f: 1228393472.000000, d: 6.069070e-315)
    xmm14 000000003e800000 (f: 1048576000.000000, d: 5.180654e-315)
    xmm15 3fef8cd2d486b2fc (f: 3565597440.000000, d: 9.859404e-01)
    Module=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9gc29.so
    Module_base_address=00007F7014BC3000
    Target=2_90_20200715_697 (Linux 4.18.0-147.13.2.el8_1.x86_64)
    CPU=amd64 (4 logical CPUs) (0x7c2a8c000 RAM)
    ----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
    (0x00007F7014BF960B [libj9gc29.so+0x3660b])
    (0x00007F7014CDAF54 [libj9gc29.so+0x117f54])
    (0x00007F7014CDBC37 [libj9gc29.so+0x118c37])
    (0x00007F7014BFA60E [libj9gc29.so+0x3760e])
    (0x00007F7014BFA64E [libj9gc29.so+0x3764e])
    (0x00007F7014BFB585 [libj9gc29.so+0x38585])
    (0x00007F70141E8780 [libjclse29.so+0x32780])
    (0x00007F70141EABD1 [libjclse29.so+0x34bd1])
    (0x00007F70141EADEE [libjclse29.so+0x34dee])
    (0x00007F6FF8345FBB [<unknown>+0x0])
    ---------------------------------------
    Unhandled exception
    Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00030000
    J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000018 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000001
    Handler1=00007F70176C30A0 Handler2=00007F7016FB2A60 InaccessibleAddress=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8
    RDI=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0 RSI=0000000000F82568 RAX=0000000000FBDC88 RBX=00007F6FF0260D40
    RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=00000000000A5C01 R8=0000000000000000 R9=0000000000000000
    R10=0000000004200000 R11=0000000000000000 R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000AE8400
    R14=0000000004200000 R15=0000000000000000
    RIP=00007F70176F3F40 GS=0000 FS=0000 RSP=00007F6FF0260CA0
    EFlags=0000000000010246 CS=0033 RBP=0000000000000000 ERR=0000000000000005
    TRAPNO=000000000000000E OLDMASK=0000000000000000 CR2=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8
    xmm0 0000003000000020 (f: 32.000000, d: 1.018558e-312)
    xmm1 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm2 00000000fe983e08 (f: 4271390208.000000, d: 2.110347e-314)
    xmm3 0000000000000001 (f: 1.000000, d: 4.940656e-324)
    xmm4 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm5 0000000000f825da (f: 16262618.000000, d: 8.034801e-317)
    xmm6 00000000fe983e08 (f: 4271390208.000000, d: 2.110347e-314)
    xmm7 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm8 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm9 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+00)
    xmm10 0000002000000020 (f: 32.000000, d: 6.790387e-313)
    xmm11 0000000049d70a38 (f: 1238829568.000000, d: 6.120632e-315)
    xmm12 000000004689a022 (f: 1183424512.000000, d: 5.846894e-315)
    xmm13 0000000047ac082f (f: 1202456576.000000, d: 5.940925e-315)
    xmm14 0000000048650dc0 (f: 1214582272.000000, d: 6.000833e-315)
    xmm15 0000000046b73e38 (f: 1186414080.000000, d: 5.861665e-315)
    Module=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so
    Module_base_address=00007F701762F000
    Target=2_90_20200715_697 (Linux 4.18.0-147.13.2.el8_1.x86_64)
    CPU=amd64 (4 logical CPUs) (0x7c2a8c000 RAM)
    ----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
    (0x00007F70176F3F40 [libj9vm29.so+0xc4f40])
    (0x00007F70176C3466 [libj9vm29.so+0x94466])
    (0x00007F70176C3E51 [libj9vm29.so+0x94e51])
    (0x00007F7017643B2C [libj9vm29.so+0x14b2c])
    (0x00007F7017641B60 [libj9vm29.so+0x12b60])
    (0x00007F70176FEC52 [libj9vm29.so+0xcfc52])
    ---------------------------------------
    #0: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x89e995) [0x7f7015944995]
    #1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x8a9390) [0x7f701594f390]
    #2: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x1615ce) [0x7f70152075ce]
    #3: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so(+0x1ac8a) [0x7f7016fb2c8a]
    #4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x128a0) [0x7f70193cd8a0]
    #5: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so(+0x6519c) [0x7f701769419c]
    #6: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so(+0x13c2c7) [0x7f701776b2c7]
    #7: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so(+0x658f3) [0x7f70176948f3]
    #8: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9vm29.so(+0x8473e) [0x7f70176b373e]
    #9: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x9465c9) [0x7f70159ec5c9]
    #10: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x1c5c00) [0x7f701526bc00]
    #11: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x152b55) [0x7f70151f8b55]
    #12: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x1f52e2) [0x7f701529b2e2]
    #13: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x1544ad) [0x7f70151fa4ad]
    #14: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x2134f5) [0x7f70152b94f5]
    #15: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x220370) [0x7f70152c6370]
    #16: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x203932) [0x7f70152a9932]
    #17: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x205686) [0x7f70152ab686]
    #18: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x562d09) [0x7f7015608d09]
    #19: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x505a5c) [0x7f70155aba5c]
    #20: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x173d27) [0x7f7015219d27]
    #21: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x174c71) [0x7f701521ac71]
    #22: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so(+0x1b7c3) [0x7f7016fb37c3]
    #23: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x176a75) [0x7f701521ca75]
    #24: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x177028) [0x7f701521d028]
    #25: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x17292b) [0x7f701521892b]
    #26: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x172df2) [0x7f7015218df2]
    #27: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x172e9a) [0x7f7015218e9a]
    #28: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9prt29.so(+0x1b7c3) [0x7f7016fb37c3]
    #29: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/lib/compressedrefs/libj9jit29.so(+0x1732f4) [0x7f70152192f4]
    ...
```

JVM details

```
    openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
    Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.21.0, JRE 11 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20200715_697 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
    OpenJ9   - 34cf4c075
    OMR      - 113e54219
    JCL      - 95bb504fbb based on jdk-11.0.8+10)
```

We are deploying our apps in Openshift 4 and these crashes has appeared (we don't know if it's a coincidence) in apps that have been updated to Spring Boot 2.3.4.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can understand I image that this is not a spring issue, its a memory issue. It could be that you do not have enough RAM. My suggestion is that you roll back some features and see where the crashes start occuring again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it isn't a memory problem due to it started happening in applications where any functionality has been added (one of those applications started to fail after one attribute in a model has been removed due to deprecation but anything more added).

Comment: @MarcosFernándezÁlvarez in case your problem is not resolved yet, try opening an issue on OpenJ9 github repo https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues along with core dump, javacore and other logs that the JVM generated on crash.